# Skype click to call issue?

Tags: css, html

Hey folks, I am making a website in html5 and I want to disable numbers to be converted into skype links with skype icon appears with numbers. My phone link html is like this:

```
<a href="tel:18662400491"><span>1-866-240-0491</span></a>
```

Should I use ?

```
`<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />`
```

And below these    css properties to do it or is there anything else ..

```
span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}
span.skype_pnh_print_container {display:inline !important;}
```

Comment: Hey Mr Alien Thanks but is it right to  use the above meta tag if i'm using html5

Comment: If you want to see if either of these approaches work, why not try them?